# SSL_connect "unexpected message" error trying to connect to rubygems on OSX Big Sur

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, homebrew, rvm

I'm on OSX Big Sur and for some reason whenever I use a ruby binary through RVM I get a:

`Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: unexpected message (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

I've tried everything in here:
https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#troubleshooting-certificate-errors

During the SSL check (`$ curl -Lks 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | ruby`)

I get a delightful

```
Unfortunately, this Ruby can't connect to rubygems.org. 
Even worse, we're not sure why.
```

Now, when I remove rvm and brew openssl and reinstall openssl but only install ruby through brew (`$ brew install ruby`)
things seem to work. But I can't manage my ruby binaries that way so I reinstalled RVM and the problem came right back.

I'm assuming I could add a pem file to the /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs folder, but what pem?

Looking for some guidance/next steps here.

### Update

I thought that maybe it was an issue with RVM since the built in ruby doesn't have the issue. So I switched to rbenv, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution Found!**

If you want to read an explaination visit his site: https://brettterpstra.com/2020/08/06/solving-rvm-and-openssl-issues-with-homebrew/

```
brew uninstall openssl --ignore-dependencies
brew tap-new $USER/old-openssl
brew extract --version=1.0.2t openssl $USER/old-openssl
brew install openssl@1.0.2t
brew install openssl
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0.2t/lib/pkgconfig \
rvm install 2.6.5 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0.2t
```

Replace the rvm version with the ruby version you want to use

et voila

Answer (score 0):

### Install and Link Against OpenSSL, not LibreSSL

Big Sur comes with LibreSSL, a non-OpenSSL binary. You will likely have to:

```
brew install openssl@1.1

# Export flags for compiling against the keg-only OpenSSL library.
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"

# Don't do this unless you really need to, as it will likely
# break some macOS native apps that depend on LibreSSL.
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
```

and then rebuild/reinstall your SSL-dependent Ruby or gems. Depending on your unique configuration, you may have other problems as well, but this should resolve 80% of most related problems.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense but doesn't work unfortunately. I also tried ```$ rvm reinstall 2.5.8 --with-openssl-dir='/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1'```